# Как убрать поворот игрока в сторону второго игрока?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Проблема, когда игрок получает урон, он начинает бежать быстрее Boost, а когда он стоит на месте и получает урон, а также касаясь Охотника, то он поворачивается к охотнику и начинает бежать на месте. Также, если я направлю игрока в сторону охотника, то при столкновении и нанесении урона, игрок также начинает поворачиваться и бежать в сторону охотника.

Код ниже -

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    const string IDLE = "m_idle_A";
    const string WALK = "m_run";
    const string DEATH = "m_death_A";

    // Your variables
    CustomAction input;
    NavMeshAgent agent;
    Animator animator;
    private Animator playerAnimator;

    [Header("Movement")]
    [SerializeField] ParticleSystem clickEffect;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask clickableLayers;

    [Header("Speed Boost")]
    [SerializeField] float speedBoost = 2.0f;
    [SerializeField] float maxBoostDuration = 7.0f;
    private float initialSpeed;
    private bool isBoosting;
    private float boostDuration;

    [Header("Health")]
    [SerializeField] int maxHealth = 2;
    private int currentHealth;
    [SerializeField] Text hpText;

    [Header("Fail Screen UI")]
    [SerializeField] RawImage FailImage;
    [SerializeField] Text YouDieAboutText;
    [SerializeField] Text YouDieText;
    [SerializeField] Text YouDieLVLAboutText;
    [SerializeField] Text YouDieLVLText;
    [SerializeField] Text DieScoreMoney;
    [SerializeField] Button MenuButton;

    [Header("Win Screen UI")]
    [SerializeField] RawImage WinImage;
    [SerializeField] Text YouWinAboutText;
    [SerializeField] Text YouWinText;
    [SerializeField] Text YouWinLVLAboutText;
    [SerializeField] Text YouWinLVLText;
    [SerializeField] Text WinScoreMoney;
    [SerializeField] Button MenuWinButton;

    [SerializeField] float lookRotationSpeed = 8.0f;

    private bool isRunning = false;

    void Awake()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        playerAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        // Initialize custom actions
        input = new CustomAction();
        AssignInputs();
    }

    void AssignInputs()
    {
        // Assign handlers to actions
        input.Main.Move.performed += ctx => ClickToMove();
    }

    void ClickToMove()
    {
        // Handle mouse click movement
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, 100, clickableLayers))
        {
            agent.destination = hit.point;

            // Play a click effect if available
            if (clickEffect != null)
            {
                Instantiate(clickEffect, hit.point + new Vector3(0, 0.1f, 0), clickEffect.transform.rotation);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        input.Enable();
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        input.Disable();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        // Initial setup at the start of the game
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        UpdateHPText();
        FailImage.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        MenuButton.gameObject.SetActive false);
        YouDieAboutText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        YouDieText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        YouDieText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        YouDieText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        DieScoreMoney.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        initialSpeed = agent.speed;
        isBoosting = false;
        boostDuration = 0f;

        // Generate random values for death score and level
        int randomDieScore = Random.Range(10, 15);
        DieScoreMoney.text = randomDieScore.ToString();

        int randomYouDieLVL = Random.Range(37, 53);
        YouDieLVLText.text = randomYouDieLVL.ToString();

        // Initial setup for win screen elements
        WinImage.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        MenuWinButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        YouWinAboutText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        YouWinText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        YouWinText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        YouWinText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        WinScoreMoney.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        // Generate random values for win score and level
        int randomWinScore = Random.Range(40, 75);
        WinScoreMoney.text = randomWinScore.ToString();

        int randomYouWinLVL = Random.Range(37, 53);
        YouWinLVLText.text = randomYouWinLVL.ToString();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Update character's facing and animations
        FaceTarget();
        SetAnimations();

        if (isRunning)
        {
            animator.Play(WALK);
        }

        if (isBoosting)
        {
            boostDuration -= Time.deltaTime;

            if (boostDuration <= 0f)
            {
                isBoosting = false;
                SetSpeed(initialSpeed);
            }
        }

        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            // Play death animation if health reaches zero
            playerAnimator.Play(DEATH);
            this.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    void FaceTarget()
    {
        // Rotate the character to face the target
        Vector3 direction = agent.destination - transform.position;

        if (direction != Vector3.zero)
        {
            Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(direction.x, 0, direction.z));
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * lookRotationSpeed);
        }
    }

    void SetAnimations()
    {
        // Control movement animations
        if (agent.velocity == Vector3.zero)
        {
            animator.Play(IDLE);
            isRunning = false;
        }
        else
        {
            isRunning = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Hunter"))
        {
            if (currentHealth > 0)
            {
                currentHealth--;
                UpdateHPText();
                ApplySpeedBoost();
            }

            if (currentHealth == 0)
            {
                // If health is zero, start a coroutine to show the fail screen objects after a delay
                StartCoroutine(ShowObjectsAfterDelay(2f));
            }
        }

        if (other.CompareTag("WinLine"))
        {
            // If the character reaches the win point, display the win screen and disable this script
            WinImage.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            MenuWinButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            YouWinAboutText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            YouWinText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            YouWinText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            YouWinText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            WinScoreMoney.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            this.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ShowObjectsAfterDelay(float delay)
    {
        // Coroutine to delay the appearance of objects on the fail screen
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        FailImage.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        MenuButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        YouDieAboutText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        YouDieText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        YouDieLVLAboutText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        YouDieLVLText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        DieScoreMoney.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void ApplySpeedBoost()
    {
        // Apply speed boost
        isBoosting = true;
        boostDuration = maxBoostDuration;
        SetSpeed(initialSpeed + speedBoost);
    }

    private void SetSpeed(float speed)
    {
        agent.speed = speed;
    }

    private void UpdateHPText()
    {
        // Update the health level text
        hpText.text = "HP: " + currentHealth;
    }
}
```

Буду готов даже закинуть на мак если поможете!!!

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Что-то не так с вопросом? Я все описан достаточно подробно

Comment: Слишком подробно.

Comment: А в чем тогда проблема?

Comment: В коде больше двухсот строк. Если вы хотите, чтобы кто-то вам помог, желательно создать минимальный воспроизводимый пример для лучшего восприятия кода. Также нужно добавить подробное описание вашей программы. Если что, это не я такой вредный, это у сайта правила такие.

Comment: Все понял, спасибо